# Return only the values that are not empty string or empty arrays from an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Until now I have the following function:

```
export const useClearEmptyAttributes = (
  obj: { [s: string]: unknown } | ArrayLike<unknown>,
) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, v]) => v));
};
```

[image]

It eliminates an empty field "phone number" which was empty, but not socialLinks (which is an array).

How can I modify my function to eliminate empty arrays too, not just empty strings?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work if you want to add checking empty arrays plus your current check:

```
export const useClearEmptyAttributes = (
  obj: { [s: string]: unknown } | ArrayLike<unknown>,
) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, v]) => Array.isArray(v)?v.length:v));
};
```

But if you want to check also for empty objects, etc it can be further modified.

Answer (score 3):

since you are targeting empty strings and empty arrays and both have `length` property you can check for the length if it is bigger than `0`:

```
export const useClearEmptyAttributes = (
  obj: { [s: string]: unknown } | ArrayLike<unknown>,
) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, v]) => v.length > 0));
};
```